# Is my Neural Network chain rule correct?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

Suppose I have the following architecture

[image]

Where $ HA_i$ and $OA_i$ are the activated values of the hidden and output nodes respectively, and $W_i$ are the weights between nodes.

> I want to find the derivative of the error $e$ w.r.t. $W_1$.

Then my chain rule is the following:

$$
 \frac{\partial e}{\partial W_1} = \left(  \frac{\partial e}{\partial OA_1} \frac{\partial OA_1}{\partial O_1} \frac{\partial O_1}{\partial HA_1} \right) \frac{\partial HA_1}{\partial H_1} \frac{\partial H_1}{\partial W_1} + \left(  \frac{\partial e}{\partial OA_2} \frac{\partial OA_2}{\partial O_2} \frac{\partial O_2}{\partial HA_1} \right) \frac{\partial HA_1}{\partial H_1} \frac{\partial H_1}{\partial W_1}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: While one can guess, you need to define your error function or else it cannot be derived.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Are you talking about - for example in the case of Softmax where the output layer is fully connected - then there are a few more derivatives? I have gotten smarter now - and my question above would apply to all activation functions (i.e.: MSE, MAD, etc) that do not depend on other output nodes.

Comment: You are asking whether your derivative is correct. Your question cannot be answered unless one knows what function you are deriving. You ask "find the derivative of the error" but you first need to answer "What is the error?"

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Well we know that error $e$ is some function $e = f(OA_1, OA_2)$; therefore, $\frac{\partial e} {\partial OA_i} = \frac{\partial f(OA_1, OA_2)} {\partial OA_i}$. Are you saying we are not allowed to write derivatives symbolically?

Comment: By the way - by definition a cost function has to have a derivative and be expressed as a sum - and a set of other conditions - so I do not see the issue. I am not saying that I can take any function - use it as a cost function - and expect results.

Comment: You must know what function your network is computing. Forget about the activation functions first. Let $f_1$ be $f_1(I_1, I_2, B_1, B_2, W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_{12}) = O_1$. Then do the same for $f_2$ calculating $O_2$. Then try and "simplify" the calculations by representing the data using matrices and vectors. You'll end up with a function like $f(i,W_1, b_1, W_2, b_2) = o$, where $i$ is the column vector containing $[I_1, I_2]$, $W_1$ and $b_1$ are the weight matrix and bias vector for the first layer, $W_2$and $b_2$ the same for the second one and $o = [O_1, O_2]$.

Comment: E.g $f_1(...) = (I_1W_1 + I_2W_3 + B_1W_5)W_7 + (I_1W_2 + I_2W_4 + B_1W_6)W_9 + B_2W11$ and $f_2$ is computed similarly. Now figure out how to write this using matrices and vectors.